# Bitmap outside runnable

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap

So my maingameloop runs and I load my Bitmaps form the R. (also some resizing)

```
Bitmap red= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.orange);
Bitmap blue = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.blue);

red= ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(red, resize, resize);
blue = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(blue, resize, resize);
```

then I paint them

```
canvas.drawBitmap(pink, (x-xmax/6), (yp[i6]), null);
```

I want to save some performance so I thought, hence the bitmaps will never change, i may also put them outside the thread? But...
When I put the first part (getting & resizing bitmaps) outside the thread, the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

What thread, UI, Async? Also, what is the crash? Likely, you are doing some work outside the UI thread, which needs to happen on the UI thread.

My suggestion is if these image resources do not change, then you should just size them appropriately for each density bucket and put them in the correct drawable folder. This will be much easier for you, as you can just set the drawable identifier on your view elements instead of loading them in at runtime.

Comment: idk just some public void run() { stuff
no error in eclipse, but at the emulator it just stops working!

Comment: Just move the resources into the correct drawable folders and reference from there.